# Multiple OR conditions using numpy Where

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to achieve a Column based or certain conditions from other columns and it's basically that, if any of these conditions are met, the results should be a NO in the NEW column, else a YES; how ever i tend to get A huge chunk of errors, even when I use the 'OR' in place of the '|', could anyone help to realize this, as the different approaches I have tried don't seem to work

```
sales["NEW"]=np.where((sales.Status=='Done' | 
                sales.Status=='out' | 
                sales.Status=='in' | 
                sales.sumPaid>dailyAmount | 
                sales.days<14), 'No','Yes')


sales["NEW"]=np.where((sales.Status==('Done|out |in') | sales.sumPaid>dailyAmount |sales.days<14), 'No','Yes')
```

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last)
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\array_ops.py
> in na_logical_op(x, y, op)
> 273         #  (xint or xbool) and (yint or bool)
> --> 274         result = op(x, y)
> 275     except TypeError:
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\roperator.py
> in ror_(left, right)
> 55 def ror_(left, right):
> ---> 56     return operator.or_(right, left)
> 57
>
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'str'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last)
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\array_ops.py
> in na_logical_op(x, y, op)
> 287             try:
> --> 288                 result = libops.scalar_binop(x, y, op)
> 289             except (
>
> pandas_libs\ops.pyx in pandas._libs.ops.scalar_binop()
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\roperator.py
> in ror_(left, right)
> 55 def ror_(left, right):
> ---> 56     return operator.or_(right, left)
> 57
>
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'bool' and 'str'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> 212
> 213 sales["NEW"]=np.where((sales.Status=='Done' |
> --> 214                     sales.Status=='out' |
> 215                     sales.Status=='in' |
> 216                     sales.sumPaid>dailyAmount |
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\common.py
> in new_method(self, other)
> 62         other = item_from_zerodim(other)
> 63
> ---> 64         return method(self, other)
> 65
> 66     return new_method
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops_*init*_.py
> in wrapper(self, other)
> 547         rvalues = extract_array(other, extract_numpy=True)
> 548
> --> 549         res_values = logical_op(lvalues, rvalues, op)
> 550         return _construct_result(self, res_values, index=self.index, name=res_name)
> 551
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\array_ops.py
> in logical_op(left, right, op)
> 364         filler = fill_int if is_self_int_dtype and is_other_int_dtype else fill_bool
> 365
> --> 366         res_values = na_logical_op(lvalues, rvalues, op)
> 367         res_values = filler(res_values)  # type: ignore
> 368
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\array_ops.py
> in na_logical_op(x, y, op)
> 296                 typ = type(y).**name**
> 297                 raise TypeError(
> --> 298                     f"Cannot perform '{op.**name**}' with a dtyped [{x.dtype}] array "
> 299                     f"and scalar of type [{typ}]"
> 300                 )
>
> TypeError: Cannot perform 'ror_' with a dtyped [object] array and
> scalar of type [bool]

Comment: Use parentheses`(sales.Status=='Done') | (sales.Status=='out') | ...`

Comment: Aside: avoid referencing columns as attributes with period. See warnings under [attribute access](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#attribute-access). Always use `[]` to access columns (i.e., `sales["Status"]`).

Answer (score 2):

The second way that you are mentioning is incorrect, it will not work by putting | inside strings.

The first way can be worked out by putting parentheses:

```
sales["NEW"]=np.where(((sales.Status=='Done') | 
                (sales.Status=='out') | 
                (sales.Status=='in') | 
                (sales.sumPaid>dailyAmount) | 
                (sales.days<14)), 'No','Yes')
```

Comment: It is actually working in my current version of numpy, might not work with the latest one maybe. `|` is the best way out anyway. Thanks @QuangHoang

Answer (score 2):

To combine consider [**`DataFrame.isin`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) where each condition is enclosed in paired parentheses. Below accesses columns by `[]` and uses functional form of mathematical operators such as [`Series.gt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html) and [`Series.lt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.lt.html):

```py
sales["NEW"] = np.where((sales["Status"].isin(['Done','out','in'])) | 
                        (sales["sumPaid"].gt(dailyAmount)) |
                        (sales["days"].lt(14)), 
                        'No',
                        'Yes')
```